# postfix configuration in main.cf not take effect

Tags: centos, email, postfix, smtp

I am in centos 7
I configured postfix's /etc/postfix/main.cf like this

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_path = /run/saslauthd
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = GSSAPI
```

and restart the postfix like this

```
systemctl restart postfix.service
```

but when I check the

```
postconf -d
```

for see my current configuration I see that above changes not take affect

output of postconf -d:

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. And again: What are the log files saying? Did you check if the configuration is overwritten at another point?

Comment: @Sven excuse me I cant comment on that post. I check the file /etc/postfix/main.cf and nothing overwritten. but when I issue the postconf -d command nothing taked affect

Comment: What are the log file saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command to check the current parameter values in effect:

```
postconf -p
```

Or just:

```
postconf
```

The command that you have used with the `-d` option will print the **default** values. You can also use the `-n` option to print only the **non-default** values, to print only what you explicitly changed.